# Using a Regular Expression how can i find if a string contains all the characters of a specific sequence in the correct sequence order?

Tags: javascript, regex

Using a javascript Regular Expression how can i find if a string contains all the characters of a specific sequence in the correct sequence order?

For example, say i had the following string

**sbvykkjwkkkTjSwbpvkoSbjpobvvwwEjknbnjsksbwybwSojoybryrbevvydTeydk**

I want to check if it contains the following characters:
 **TEST** 
in that order but not necessarily next to each other.

Comment: `'sbvykkjwkkkTjSwbpvkoSbjpobvvwwEjknbnjsksbwybwSojoybryrbevvydTeydk'.match(/T.*E.*S.*T/)`

Comment: What have you tried so far? What part did you struggle with? How did you determine that a regex is the right solution to this problem? Will the sequence you're looking for be dynamic?

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants to solve the regex problem by *NOT* using any regex library/implementation. It sure do look like a programming interview problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let reg = /.*T.*E.*S.*T.*/

let check = reg.test('sbvykkjwkkkTjSwbpvkoSbjpobvvwwEjknbnjsksbwybwSojoybryrbevvydTeydk')
console.log(check)
```

Comment: thanks that works, i guess i was overthinking things.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the "0 or more" wildcard pattern: `.*`. This will test for zero or more of any character. Then just order the test string with those in between.

### Edit

If you want the pattern not to match when any other characters from the test string match out of order, then you should specify which "any" character could be in between the test characters, as in, "besides  which characters are valid padding?".

```js
const positiveString = 'sbvykkjwkkkTjwbpvkobjpobvvwwEjknbnjsksbwybwSojoybryrbevvydTeydk';
const negativeString1 = 'sbvykkjwkkkTjwbpvkobSjpobvvwwEjknbnjsksbSwybwSojoybryrSbevvydTeydk';
const negativeString2 = 'asdfasdfasdfTasfasfdasfdSasfasfasdfasdfasfdEasdfaTsdfasdf';

const regex = /T[^TEST]*?E[^TEST]*?S[^TEST]*?T/;

const match = positiveString.match(regex);
const noMatch1 = negativeString1.match(regex);
const noMatch2 = negativeString2.match(regex);

console.log('Match: ', match, '\nNo-match: ', noMatch1, '\nAlso No-match: ', noMatch2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Intercalate `.*` between your characters to match anything in between.

You make a generic function that generates a tester function like this:

```js
const testSequence = pattern => str => new RegExp(pattern.split('').join('.*')).test(str);

const tester1 = testSequence('TEST');
const tester2 = testSequence('HELLO');

console.log(tester1('sbvykkjwkkkTjSwbpvkoSbjpobvvwwEjknbnjsksbwybwSojoybryrbevvydTeydk'));
console.log(tester1('TEST'));
console.log(tester1('TNT'));
console.log(tester2('HhEeLlLlOo'));
```